# ipython 5.1.0 stops after executing an input

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

I am using Win 10 64 bit, with latest Anaconda 4.3.1 installed, which includes Python 3.6.0 and ipython 5.1.0.

The code I am trying to run

```
# Simple Python program to Add Two Numbers

number1 = input(" Please Enter the First Number: ")
number2 = input(" Please Enter the second number: ")

# Using arithmetic + Operator to add two numbers
sum = float(number1) + float(number2)
print('The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}'.format(number1, number2, sum))
```

The problem is when executing input function the Ipython interpreter terminates.
The same code works fine with python

[image: Screenshot regarding the issue]

Comment: There's nothing I can see wrong with your code, and running the same code works for me. :-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the ipython package to latest 6.0.0 solved the issue

You could use

`conda update ipython`

or update ipython from within Anaconda Navigator